# Android react native proximity sensor

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I just started with react native and an idea of timer application occurred to me, but the problem is that I want to use the proximity sensor of android. I wanted to know if it is possible to use it and if it is in what way they recommend me or if they can guide me to start using it. I appreciate any help possible.